# How to upgrade your Spring Boot 2.x application to use SnakeYAML 2.0?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, yaml, snakeyaml

What steps should be taken to upgrade a Spring Boot 2.x application and enable it to use SnakeYAML 2.0 instead of the vulnerable version of snakeyaml that it currently utilizes?

Answer (score 3):

I would like to contribute a solution to the community regarding a common issue that many are facing. The problem stems from the fact that the yaml parser used in spring boot called snakeyaml v1.33, has known security vulnerabilities (CVEs). While some may consider these vulnerabilities to be a false positives based on the way snakeyaml is being used in their application, they still present a potential security risk. The only solution is to upgrade to spring boot 2.7.10 or a later version that includes a fix, allowing you to upgrade the version of snakeyaml to 2.0. If you were to upgrade to snakeyaml version 2.0 on any version of spring boot below version 2.7.10 you would get the following error:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.yaml.snakeyaml.representer.Representer: method 'void <init>()' not found
```

I would like to offer a solution to address this issue. Assuming that you cannot upgrade to a newer version of spring boot and using properties-based configuration is not a viable option. Please use the code below allow for the configuration of snakeyaml 2.0 in your project.

```java
package com.example.demo.yaml;


import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;


import org.yaml.snakeyaml.DumperOptions;
import org.yaml.snakeyaml.LoaderOptions;
import org.yaml.snakeyaml.Yaml;
import org.yaml.snakeyaml.constructor.BaseConstructor;
import org.yaml.snakeyaml.constructor.Constructor;
import org.yaml.snakeyaml.constructor.SafeConstructor;
import org.yaml.snakeyaml.error.Mark;
import org.yaml.snakeyaml.nodes.CollectionNode;
import org.yaml.snakeyaml.nodes.MappingNode;
import org.yaml.snakeyaml.nodes.Node;
import org.yaml.snakeyaml.nodes.NodeTuple;
import org.yaml.snakeyaml.nodes.ScalarNode;
import org.yaml.snakeyaml.nodes.Tag;
import org.yaml.snakeyaml.representer.Representer;
import org.yaml.snakeyaml.resolver.Resolver;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.config.YamlProcessor;
import org.springframework.boot.origin.Origin;
import org.springframework.boot.origin.OriginTrackedValue;
import org.springframework.boot.origin.TextResourceOrigin;
import org.springframework.boot.origin.TextResourceOrigin.Location;
import org.springframework.core.io.Resource;
import org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils;

/**
 * Class to load {@code .yml} files into a map of {@code String} to
 * {@link OriginTrackedValue}.
 *
 * @author Madhura Bhave
 * @author Phillip Webb
 */
class CustomOriginTrackedYamlLoader extends YamlProcessor {

    private static final boolean HAS_RESOLVER_LIMIT = ReflectionUtils.findMethod(Resolver.class, "addImplicitResolver",
            Tag.class, Pattern.class, String.class, int.class) != null;

    private final Resource resource;

    CustomOriginTrackedYamlLoader(Resource resource) {
        this.resource = resource;
        setResources(resource);
    }

    @Override
    protected Yaml createYaml() {
        LoaderOptions loaderOptions = new LoaderOptions();
        loaderOptions.setAllowDuplicateKeys(false);
        loaderOptions.setMaxAliasesForCollections(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
        loaderOptions.setAllowRecursiveKeys(true);
        return createYaml(loaderOptions);
    }

    private Yaml createYaml(LoaderOptions loaderOptions) {
        BaseConstructor constructor = new OriginTrackingConstructor(loaderOptions);
        DumperOptions dumperOptions = new DumperOptions();
        Representer representer = new Representer(dumperOptions);
        Resolver resolver = HAS_RESOLVER_LIMIT ? new NoTimestampResolverWithLimit() : new NoTimestampResolver();
        return new Yaml(constructor, representer, dumperOptions, loaderOptions, resolver);
    }
    List<Map<String, Object>> load() {
        final List<Map<String, Object>> result = new ArrayList<>();
        process((properties, map) -> result.add(getFlattenedMap(map)));
        return result;
    }

    /**
     * {@link Constructor} that tracks property origins.
     */
    private class OriginTrackingConstructor extends SafeConstructor {

        OriginTrackingConstructor(LoaderOptions loadingConfig) {
            super(loadingConfig);
        }

        @Override
        public Object getData() throws NoSuchElementException {
            Object data = super.getData();
            if (data instanceof CharSequence && ((CharSequence) data).length() == 0) {
                return null;
            }
            return data;
        }

        @Override
        protected Object constructObject(Node node) {
            if (node instanceof CollectionNode && ((CollectionNode<?>) node).getValue().isEmpty()) {
                return constructTrackedObject(node, super.constructObject(node));
            }
            if (node instanceof ScalarNode) {
                if (!(node instanceof CustomOriginTrackedYamlLoader.KeyScalarNode)) {
                    return constructTrackedObject(node, super.constructObject(node));
                }
            }
            if (node instanceof MappingNode) {
                replaceMappingNodeKeys((MappingNode) node);
            }
            return super.constructObject(node);
        }

        private void replaceMappingNodeKeys(MappingNode node) {
            node.setValue(node.getValue().stream().map(CustomOriginTrackedYamlLoader.KeyScalarNode::get).collect(Collectors.toList()));
        }

        private Object constructTrackedObject(Node node, Object value) {
            Origin origin = getOrigin(node);
            return OriginTrackedValue.of(getValue(value), origin);
        }

        private Object getValue(Object value) {
            return (value != null) ? value : "";
        }

        private Origin getOrigin(Node node) {
            Mark mark = node.getStartMark();
            Location location = new Location(mark.getLine(), mark.getColumn());
            return new TextResourceOrigin(CustomOriginTrackedYamlLoader.this.resource, location);
        }

    }

    /**
     * {@link ScalarNode} that replaces the key node in a {@link NodeTuple}.
     */
    private static class KeyScalarNode extends ScalarNode {

        KeyScalarNode(ScalarNode node) {
            super(node.getTag(), node.getValue(), node.getStartMark(), node.getEndMark(), node.getScalarStyle());
        }

        static NodeTuple get(NodeTuple nodeTuple) {
            Node keyNode = nodeTuple.getKeyNode();
            Node valueNode = nodeTuple.getValueNode();
            return new NodeTuple(CustomOriginTrackedYamlLoader.KeyScalarNode.get(keyNode), valueNode);
        }

        private static Node get(Node node) {
            if (node instanceof ScalarNode) {
                return new CustomOriginTrackedYamlLoader.KeyScalarNode((ScalarNode) node);
            }
            return node;
        }

    }

    /**
     * {@link Resolver} that limits {@link Tag#TIMESTAMP} tags.
     */
    private static class NoTimestampResolver extends Resolver {

        @Override
        public void addImplicitResolver(Tag tag, Pattern regexp, String first) {
            if (tag == Tag.TIMESTAMP) {
                return;
            }
            super.addImplicitResolver(tag, regexp, first);
        }

    }

    /**
     * {@link Resolver} that limits {@link Tag#TIMESTAMP} tags.
     */
    private static class NoTimestampResolverWithLimit extends Resolver {

        @Override
        public void addImplicitResolver(Tag tag, Pattern regexp, String first, int limit) {
            if (tag == Tag.TIMESTAMP) {
                return;
            }
            super.addImplicitResolver(tag, regexp, first, limit);
        }

    }

}
```

```java
package com.example.demo.yaml;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import org.springframework.boot.env.OriginTrackedMapPropertySource;
import org.springframework.boot.env.PropertySourceLoader;
import org.springframework.core.env.PropertySource;
import org.springframework.core.io.Resource;
import org.springframework.util.ClassUtils;

/**
 * Strategy to load '.yml' (or '.yaml') files into a {@link PropertySource}.
 *
 * @author Dave Syer
 * @author Phillip Webb
 * @author Andy Wilkinson
 * @since 1.0.0
 */
public class CustomYamlPropertySourceLoader implements PropertySourceLoader {

    @Override
    public String[] getFileExtensions() {
        return new String[] { "yml", "yaml" };
    }

    @Override
    public List<PropertySource<?>> load(String name, Resource resource) throws IOException {
        if (!ClassUtils.isPresent("org.yaml.snakeyaml.Yaml", getClass().getClassLoader())) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(
                    "Attempted to load " + name + " but snakeyaml was not found on the classpath");
        }
        List<Map<String, Object>> loaded = new CustomOriginTrackedYamlLoader(resource).load();
        if (loaded.isEmpty()) {
            return Collections.emptyList();
        }
        List<PropertySource<?>> propertySources = new ArrayList<>(loaded.size());
        for (int i = 0; i < loaded.size(); i++) {
            String documentNumber = (loaded.size() != 1) ? " (document #" + i + ")" : "";
            propertySources.add(new OriginTrackedMapPropertySource(name + documentNumber,
                    Collections.unmodifiableMap(loaded.get(i)), true));
        }
        return propertySources;
    }

}
```

src/main/resources/META-INF/spring.factories

```
# PropertySource Loaders
org.springframework.boot.env.PropertySourceLoader=\
org.springframework.boot.env.PropertiesPropertySourceLoader,\
com.example.demo.yaml.CustomYamlPropertySourceLoader
```

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.8</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.yaml</groupId>
                <artifactId>snakeyaml</artifactId>
                <version>2.0</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

link to github: [Spring-Boot-SnakeYAML2-Upgrade](https://github.com/StevenBuglione/spring-boot-2-snakeyaml2-upgrade)